# Обновляющаяся строка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать строку обновляющейся? Хочу подсчитывать количество отправляемых скриптом http-запросов в минуту и выводить это всё в одну и ту же строку, а не каждый раз в новую. Например, если я напишу `print(string)` и захочу вывести эту строка дважды, то вывод будет следующим:

```
Requests per minute: 10;
Requests per minute: 20;
```

А надо сделать так, чтобы число в этой строке было обновляемым.

Comment: У вас какой питон? Третий?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Да, Python 3.5.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Text Progress Bar in the Console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3173320/4279).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте символ возврата курсора (\b):

```
from __future__ import print_function #for python 2.x
print ("123\b\b", end="")
print ("55", end="")
```

Выведет на печать 155 в итоге, потому что после 123 курсор сместится на 2 позиции назад.

Можно использовать перевод курсора в начало строки, если вы собираетесь перепечатать всю строку целиком:

```
print ("123\r", end="")
print ("456", end="")
```

Comment: Получаю ошибку `invalid syntax` в строке `print('Successful requests: ' + success + '\r', end='')`, где стрелка указывает на символ `=`

Comment: str(success) попробуйте...

Comment: Добавьте `flush=True`. Иначе результат можете не увидеть, например: `print('Requests per minute: {:3d}'.format(rpm), end='\r', flush=True)` (если всегда `rpm < 1000`).