# Функция print() без создания новой строки с заменой предыдущего значения

Tags: python

Подобные вопросы по ссылкам, но решений я не нашел

[Обновляющаяся строка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561305/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0?rq=1)

[Перебор цифр без создания новой строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879109/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Есть цикл:

```
for ......
    ......
    print(..%)
    ......
```

который выводит:

```
1%
4%
8%
...
95%
100%
```

Вопрос: как сделать сделать чтобы проценты менялись, а не дописывались?
т.е. чтобы сначала вывел

```
1%
```

затем заменил 1% на 4%

```
4%
```

и так менял цифры до 100%.

Comment: Вариант `print(i, end='\r')` разве не работает?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перебор цифр без создания новой строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879109/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Вариант `print(i, end='\r')` у меня не работает. Наверно, что-то не понимаю.

Comment: Не отображается? Или отображается на следующей строке? Перенаправление STDOUT используете?

Comment: В конструкции `print(i, end='\r')` в цикле получаю только последнее значение. Про перенаправления сейчас читаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
import time
for p in range(101):
    print(f"\r{p}%...", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.05)
print("done")
```

Comment: А `flush` нужен? Всё равно ведь это только с консолью работает.

Comment: Или фишка в том, что PyCharm использует перенаправление?

Comment: Проверил - у меня работает и без `flush=True` (в PyCharm).

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
import time
for i in range(100):
    print(i, end='\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Эта конструкция почему-то не работает (Python 3.7)/(PyCharm 2020.2)

Comment: @AlexSam Работает тока в терминале ;)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать [управляющие символы](https://www.schoolsw3.com/python/python_strings_escape.php)

Конкретно для ваших целей нужны `\r` или `\b`

**Символ `\r`** перемещает курсор (который как бы печатает символы) в начало строки (идентично нажатию клавиши `Home` на клавиатуре). После чего символы заменяются на новые (как при нажатом `insert`)

При этом важно учесть, что не перезаписанные символы останутся

Например:

```py
print("abcd\rAB ") # "AB d"
```

Вначале напечатает первые четыре символа: `abcd|`

Потом сдвинет курсор в начало: `|abcd`

И напечатает `AB`  вместо `abc`: `AB |d`

**Символ `\b`** возвращает курсор только на **один** символ назад (аналогично нажатию `←` на клавиатуре).

Например:

```py
print("abcde\b\b\b 1") # "ab 1e"
```

Печатаем `abcde|`

Сдвигаем курсор на 3 символа назад: `ab|cde`

печатаем  `1`: `ab 1|e`